# Angular - Vimeo API: Error No user credentials were provided

Tags: angular, postman, vimeo-api

While trying to connect to `Vimeo` API I get this error `No user credentials were provided.`

I've tried also in postman where I get the same results. I have checked the `Client ID` + `Secret` many time and I'm sure is not the issue.

Could someone give me a hand with this?

```
conectarseAVimeo() {
    const configUrl = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 

        'Authorization': 'basic base64_encode(*CLIENTID:SECRET*(Hidden)',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
      })
    }
    
    const body = {
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'scope': 'public'
    };
    const url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client'

    this.http.post<any>(url, body, configUrl)
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
  }
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```